# In a list of items, keep first item and remove the rest that match a pattern (using python)

Tags: python, pattern-matching

```
list = ['Scott 83% top', 'Tony 22%', 'Tony B 12% failed', 'James 66%', 'James Lipton 9%', 'Adams 76% excellent', 'Scott Brown 53%']    
pattern = ['Scott', 'Tony', 'James']
```

I want the result to be:

```
['Scott 83% top', 'Tony 22%', 'James 66%']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ok?

```
In [1]: list = ['Scott 83% top', 'Tony 22%', 'Tony B 12% failed', 'James 66%', 'James Lipton 9%', 'Adams 76% excellent', 'Scott Brown 53%']

In [2]: pattern = ['Scott', 'Tony', 'James']    

In [3]: l=[]

In [4]: for item in list:                                                                                                                                                   
   ...:     for p in pattern:
   ...:         if item.startswith(p):
   ...:             l.append(item)
   ...:             pattern.remove(p)
   ...:             break
   ...:             

In [5]: l
Out[5]: ['Scott 83% top', 'Tony 22%', 'James 66%']
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it w/o `startswith`? What if the first item was 'A.Scott 83% top'? The code would fail.

Comment: @koogee if you want to do a "contains" check, you could do `if p in item:`